# How to style Joomla 2.5 article's intro text?

Tags: joomla, styles, customization, joomla2.5, article

It's very strange but I haven't found a really good solution by googling `joomla style intro text`.

I want that the current output:

```
<div class="item-content">
    <p>Intro Text</p>
    <p>Full Text</p>
</div>
```

to be replaced by:

```
<div class="item-content">
    <div class="introtext"><p>Intro Text</p></div>
    <div class="fulltext"><p>Full Text</p></div>
</div>
```

I was sure that Joomla itself should have declared such a class for introtext or at least should have a configurable option for that.

**What I do NOT want:**

- A Joomla 1.x or Joomla 1.5 solution
- A manual way until there is not
  an extension-base solution (which is more more strange!)

---

**UPDATE after [{THIS}](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12230116/315550) answer**

Now I have a problem with `$this->item->introtext`, `$this->item->fulltext` and `$this->item->text`.

I expect `$this->item->introtext` to show ONLY introtext, but it also contains the contents AFTER **READ MORE**.

What property should I use to only include contents BEFORE **READ MORE**, not anything else?

I don't expect that the `$this->item->introtext` content be affected by `Show Intro Text` parameter in article options. It is expected that only `$this->item->text` cares about it. Am I right?

**Note:** `$this->item->fulltext` works as expected and outputs only the contents AFTER the **READ MORE**.

---

In case of disabling `Show Intro Text` parameter in article options, all of the 3 variables, return the text after **READ MORE**. This should really be considered as a bug.

It would be more wisely to have a variable to return only intro text (in any situation), a variable to return only full text (in any situation), and a variable to include/exclude introtext according to the article parameter: `Show Intro Text`

Comment: Just as hint, if you want to use content plugins in fulltexts to:
`$ftext = JHTML::_('content.prepare', $this->item->fulltext);
echo $ftext;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Joomla 3.3.0 it just works as you expected:

```
<div id="introtext"><?php echo$this->item->introtext; ?></div>
<div id="fulltext"><?php echo $this->item->fulltext; ?></div>
```

(in templates/your_template_name/html/com_content/article/default.php)

Answer (score 3):

All you need to do is add a template override. You need to make a copy of this file:

```
/JOOMLA INSTALL/components/com_content/views/article/tmpl/default.php
```

Make any changes to the code that you want, then upload it here:

```
/JOOMLA INSTALL/templates/flexibility/html/com_content/article/default.php
```

Simple as that.

Comment: Perfect! I really appreciate your answer. I thought that I had to only change the core component. And you showed me the standard way :)

Comment: I've updated my question according to your useful answer. Thanks again.